# SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 1

Tags: javascript, json

Yes, i know that the problem here is a bad formated JSON, but i was read a lot of questions,the whole JSON string and even all of this, i can't figure out the problem itself.

I'm getting a json string response from the server and trying to parse with `json.parse(string)` but always get the same error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 1
>       at JSON.parse ()
>       at :1:6

Anyone can help me with this? I can't see the problem.

Here is the raw string formated:

`"{'0': [{'text': 'conquistar', 'value': 1559.0}, {'text': 'mujer', 'value': 1559.0}, {'text': 'no', 'value': 866.0}, {'text': 'olvidar', 'value': 842.0}, {'text': 'libros', 'value': 842.0}, {'text': 'últimos', 'value': 645.0}, {'text': 'imdb', 'value': 645.0}, {'text': 'años', 'value': 645.0}, {'text': 'encontrarás', 'value': 519.0}, {'text': 'donde', 'value': 519.0}, {'text': 'páginas', 'value': 519.0}, {'text': 'tatuaje', 'value': 519.0}, {'text': 'sabías', 'value': 481.0}, {'text': 'potter', 'value': 481.0}, {'text': 'universo', 'value': 481.0}, {'text': 'harry', 'value': 481.0}, {'text': 'del', 'value': 481.0}, {'text': 'datos', 'value': 481.0}, {'text': 'cómo', 'value': 388.0}, {'text': 'n', 'value': 353.0}, {'text': 'netflix', 'value': 256.0}, {'text': 'deberías', 'value': 256.0}, {'text': 'bicicleta', 'value': 255.0}, {'text': 'amo', 'value': 255.0}, {'text': 'mi', 'value': 255.0}, {'text': 'incestuosas', 'value': 242.0}, {'text': 'julio', 'value': 242.0}, {'text': 'cortázar', 'value': 242.0}, {'text': 'relaciones', 'value': 242.0}, {'text': 'decir', 'value': 236.0}, {'text': 'frases', 'value': 236.0}, {'text': 'adiós', 'value': 236.0}, {'text': 'poder', 'value': 215.0}, {'text': 'mundo', 'value': 215.0}, {'text': 'anorexia', 'value': 215.0}, {'text': 'moda', 'value': 215.0}, {'text': 'los', 'value': 202.0}, {'text': 'a', 'value': 167.0}, {'text': 'like', 'value': 147.0}, {'text': 'ves', 'value': 147.0}, {'text': 'esto', 'value': 147.0}, {'text': 'facebook', 'value': 147.0}, {'text': 'das', 'value': 147.0}, {'text': 'próximo', 'value': 129.0}, {'text': 'según', 'value': 128.0}, {'text': 'único', 'value': 127.0}, {'text': 'edificio', 'value': 127.0}, {'text': 'construido', 'value': 127.0}, {'text': 'cartas', 'value': 127.0}, {'text': 'si', 'value': 126.0}, {'text': 'psicópata', 'value': 108.0}, {'text': 'eres', 'value': 108.0}, {'text': 'definir', 'value': 108.0}, {'text': 'tus', 'value': 108.0}, {'text': 'gustos', 'value': 108.0}, {'text': 'podrían', 'value': 108.0}, {'text': 'mexicanos', 'value': 105.0}, {'text': 'conocer', 'value': 105.0}, {'text': 'debes', 'value': 105.0}, {'text': 'ilustradores', 'value': 105.0}, {'text': 'cerebro', 'value': 96.0}, {'text': 'porno', 'value': 96.0}, {'text': 'afecta', 'value': 96.0}, {'text': 'nunca', 'value': 91.0}, {'text': 'películas', 'value': 89.0}, {'text': 'qué', 'value': 82.0}, {'text': 'opción', 'value': 80.0}, {'text': 'negro', 'value': 80.0}, {'text': 'vestir', 'value': 80.0}, {'text': 'mejores', 'value': 78.0}, {'text': 'de', 'value': 67.0}, {'text': 'por', 'value': 65.0}, {'text': 'amor', 'value': 64.0}, {'text': 'en', 'value': 64.0}, {'text': 'directores', 'value': 63.0}, {'text': 'cine', 'value': 63.0}, {'text': 'nuevos', 'value': 63.0}, {'text': 'terror', 'value': 63.0}, {'text': 'para', 'value': 61.0}, {'text': 'le', 'value': 61.0}, {'text': 'pasa', 'value': 61.0}, {'text': 'lo', 'value': 61.0}, {'text': 'la', 'value': 59.0}, {'text': 'las', 'value': 58.0}, {'text': 'un', 'value': 56.0}, {'text': 'el', 'value': 56.0}, {'text': 'mejor', 'value': 47.0}, {'text': 'baile', 'value': 45.0}, {'text': 'erótico', 'value': 45.0}, {'text': 'que', 'value': 42.0}, {'text': 'elvie', 'value': 40.0}, {'text': 'videojuego', 'value': 40.0}, {'text': 'exclusivo', 'value': 40.0}, {'text': 'vagina', 'value': 40.0}, {'text': 'ver', 'value': 39.0}, {'text': 'una', 'value': 39.0}, {'text': 'tu', 'value': 39.0}, {'text': 'canciones', 'value': 38.0}, {'text': 'dije', 'value': 32.0}, {'text': 'versos', 'value': 32.0}, {'text': 'tengo', 'value': 32.0}, {'text': 'te', 'value': 32.0}, {'text': 'siempre', 'value': 32.0}, {'text': 'fiesta', 'value': 32.0}, {'text': 'pena', 'value': 32.0}, {'text': 'pero', 'value': 32.0}, {'text': 'dan', 'value': 32.0}, {'text': 'bailas', 'value': 32.0}, {'text': 'ganará', 'value': 32.0}, {'text': 'dicaprio', 'value': 32.0}, {'text': 'oscar', 'value': 32.0}, {'text': 'todo', 'value': 30.0}, {'text': 'inspiró', 'value': 29.0}, {'text': 'bohemia', 'value': 29.0}, {'text': 'diseñadora', 'value': 29.0}, {'text': 'klimt', 'value': 29.0}, {'text': 'gustav', 'value': 29.0}, {'text': 'estás', 'value': 27.0}, {'text': 'soñar', 'value': 27.0}, {'text': 'señal', 'value': 27.0}, {'text': 'público', 'value': 27.0}, {'text': 'desnudo', 'value': 27.0}, {'text': 'consumes', 'value': 25.0}, {'text': 'rostro', 'value': 25.0}, {'text': 'droga', 'value': 25.0}, {'text': 'fotografías', 'value': 25.0}, {'text': 'con', 'value': 17.0}, {'text': 'es', 'value': 13.0}, {'text': 'hacer', 'value': 10.0}, {'text': 'tatuajes', 'value': 9.0}, {'text': 'wars', 'value': 9.0}, {'text': 'star', 'value': 9.0}, {'text': 'inspirados', 'value': 9.0}, {'text': 'razones', 'value': 9.0}, {'text': 'vida', 'value': 8.0}, {'text': 'zombies', 'value': 6.0}, {'text': 'novelas', 'value': 6.0}, {'text': 'amante', 'value': 6.0}, {'text': 'marciales', 'value': 6.0}, {'text': 'tiene', 'value': 6.0}, {'text': 'artes', 'value': 6.0}, {'text': 'trip', 'value': 2.0}, {'text': 'road', 'value': 2.0}, {'text': 'perdonar', 'value': 1.0}, {'text': 'posible', 'value': 1.0}, {'text': 'infidelidad', 'value': 1.0}]}"`

Comment: You need to use double quotes in the raw json for key and value strings, not single quotes. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Example

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just use **"** instead of **'** in your json:

```js
var test = JSON.parse('{"0": [{"text": "conquistar", "value": 1559.0}, {"text": "mujer", "value": 1559.0}, {"text": "no", "value": 866.0}, {"text": "olvidar", "value": 842.0}, {"text": "libros", "value": 842.0}, {"text": "últimos", "value": 645.0}, {"text": "imdb", "value": 645.0}, {"text": "años", "value": 645.0}, {"text": "encontrarás", "value": 519.0}, {"text": "donde", "value": 519.0}, {"text": "páginas", "value": 519.0}, {"text": "tatuaje", "value": 519.0}, {"text": "sabías", "value": 481.0}, {"text": "potter", "value": 481.0}, {"text": "universo", "value": 481.0}, {"text": "harry", "value": 481.0}, {"text": "del", "value": 481.0}, {"text": "datos", "value": 481.0}, {"text": "cómo", "value": 388.0}, {"text": "n", "value": 353.0}, {"text": "netflix", "value": 256.0}, {"text": "deberías", "value": 256.0}, {"text": "bicicleta", "value": 255.0}, {"text": "amo", "value": 255.0}, {"text": "mi", "value": 255.0}, {"text": "incestuosas", "value": 242.0}, {"text": "julio", "value": 242.0}, {"text": "cortázar", "value": 242.0}, {"text": "relaciones", "value": 242.0}, {"text": "decir", "value": 236.0}, {"text": "frases", "value": 236.0}, {"text": "adiós", "value": 236.0}, {"text": "poder", "value": 215.0}, {"text": "mundo", "value": 215.0}, {"text": "anorexia", "value": 215.0}, {"text": "moda", "value": 215.0}, {"text": "los", "value": 202.0}, {"text": "a", "value": 167.0}, {"text": "like", "value": 147.0}, {"text": "ves", "value": 147.0}, {"text": "esto", "value": 147.0}, {"text": "facebook", "value": 147.0}, {"text": "das", "value": 147.0}, {"text": "próximo", "value": 129.0}, {"text": "según", "value": 128.0}, {"text": "único", "value": 127.0}, {"text": "edificio", "value": 127.0}, {"text": "construido", "value": 127.0}, {"text": "cartas", "value": 127.0}, {"text": "si", "value": 126.0}, {"text": "psicópata", "value": 108.0}, {"text": "eres", "value": 108.0}, {"text": "definir", "value": 108.0}, {"text": "tus", "value": 108.0}, {"text": "gustos", "value": 108.0}, {"text": "podrían", "value": 108.0}, {"text": "mexicanos", "value": 105.0}, {"text": "conocer", "value": 105.0}, {"text": "debes", "value": 105.0}, {"text": "ilustradores", "value": 105.0}, {"text": "cerebro", "value": 96.0}, {"text": "porno", "value": 96.0}, {"text": "afecta", "value": 96.0}, {"text": "nunca", "value": 91.0}, {"text": "películas", "value": 89.0}, {"text": "qué", "value": 82.0}, {"text": "opción", "value": 80.0}, {"text": "negro", "value": 80.0}, {"text": "vestir", "value": 80.0}, {"text": "mejores", "value": 78.0}, {"text": "de", "value": 67.0}, {"text": "por", "value": 65.0}, {"text": "amor", "value": 64.0}, {"text": "en", "value": 64.0}, {"text": "directores", "value": 63.0}, {"text": "cine", "value": 63.0}, {"text": "nuevos", "value": 63.0}, {"text": "terror", "value": 63.0}, {"text": "para", "value": 61.0}, {"text": "le", "value": 61.0}, {"text": "pasa", "value": 61.0}, {"text": "lo", "value": 61.0}, {"text": "la", "value": 59.0}, {"text": "las", "value": 58.0}, {"text": "un", "value": 56.0}, {"text": "el", "value": 56.0}, {"text": "mejor", "value": 47.0}, {"text": "baile", "value": 45.0}, {"text": "erótico", "value": 45.0}, {"text": "que", "value": 42.0}, {"text": "elvie", "value": 40.0}, {"text": "videojuego", "value": 40.0}, {"text": "exclusivo", "value": 40.0}, {"text": "vagina", "value": 40.0}, {"text": "ver", "value": 39.0}, {"text": "una", "value": 39.0}, {"text": "tu", "value": 39.0}, {"text": "canciones", "value": 38.0}, {"text": "dije", "value": 32.0}, {"text": "versos", "value": 32.0}, {"text": "tengo", "value": 32.0}, {"text": "te", "value": 32.0}, {"text": "siempre", "value": 32.0}, {"text": "fiesta", "value": 32.0}, {"text": "pena", "value": 32.0}, {"text": "pero", "value": 32.0}, {"text": "dan", "value": 32.0}, {"text": "bailas", "value": 32.0}, {"text": "ganará", "value": 32.0}, {"text": "dicaprio", "value": 32.0}, {"text": "oscar", "value": 32.0}, {"text": "todo", "value": 30.0}, {"text": "inspiró", "value": 29.0}, {"text": "bohemia", "value": 29.0}, {"text": "diseñadora", "value": 29.0}, {"text": "klimt", "value": 29.0}, {"text": "gustav", "value": 29.0}, {"text": "estás", "value": 27.0}, {"text": "soñar", "value": 27.0}, {"text": "señal", "value": 27.0}, {"text": "público", "value": 27.0}, {"text": "desnudo", "value": 27.0}, {"text": "consumes", "value": 25.0}, {"text": "rostro", "value": 25.0}, {"text": "droga", "value": 25.0}, {"text": "fotografías", "value": 25.0}, {"text": "con", "value": 17.0}, {"text": "es", "value": 13.0}, {"text": "hacer", "value": 10.0}, {"text": "tatuajes", "value": 9.0}, {"text": "wars", "value": 9.0}, {"text": "star", "value": 9.0}, {"text": "inspirados", "value": 9.0}, {"text": "razones", "value": 9.0}, {"text": "vida", "value": 8.0}, {"text": "zombies", "value": 6.0}, {"text": "novelas", "value": 6.0}, {"text": "amante", "value": 6.0}, {"text": "marciales", "value": 6.0}, {"text": "tiene", "value": 6.0}, {"text": "artes", "value": 6.0}, {"text": "trip", "value": 2.0}, {"text": "road", "value": 2.0}, {"text": "perdonar", "value": 1.0}, {"text": "posible", "value": 1.0}, {"text": "infidelidad", "value": 1.0}]}');

console.log(test);
```

Answer (score 6):

ECMA-404 The JSON Data Interchange Standard says:

> A string is a sequence of zero or more Unicode characters, wrapped in **double quotes**

In your case you have single quoutes

So you can use `str.replace("'", """);`