# JSON parsing error Jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I am using a web server that returns `JSON` but jquery fails to parse that json and shows following error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 1
```

The data returned by api seems to be fine. I copied the response in my js file and tried to parse it with `$.parseJSON` but I get the same error. Here is the code snippet containing returned `json` and a call to `parseJSON`

```
var jso = "['ADCP1_SNR_CH1','ADCP1_SNR_CH2','ADCP1_SNR_CH3','ADCP1_RADVEL_CH0']";
        var dt = $.parseJSON(jso);
```

My question is, what is wrong with the above `json` array? why do I bump into this error?

Comment: http://json.org/ You can run the JSON through a service like JSONlint.com too. Basically, string literals have to be within double quotes.

Comment: Also duplicate of [SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42356294/215552). 9 times out of 10, searching for the error message gets you what you want. Someone with your rep should know we expect people to do their research...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that single quotes are not valid in JSON.  Swap the single and double quotes, like so:

```
var jso = '["ADCP1_SNR_CH1","ADCP1_SNR_CH2","ADCP1_SNR_CH3","ADCP1_RADVEL_CH0"]';
    var dt = $.parseJSON(jso);
```

Alternatively, you can escape the quotes like this:

```
var jso = "[\"ADCP1_SNR_CH1\",\"ADCP1_SNR_CH2\",\"ADCP1_SNR_CH3\",\"ADCP1_RADVEL_CH0\"]";
    var dt = $.parseJSON(jso);
```

Answer (score 2):

JSON does not support single quotes (`'`). It must use double quotes:

```js
var jso = '["ADCP1_SNR_CH1","ADCP1_SNR_CH2","ADCP1_SNR_CH3","ADCP1_RADVEL_CH0"]';
var dt = $.parseJSON(jso);
console.log(dt);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```